# Javascript tabs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

When I click a tab on my `navbar` it will go to the tab, but once I move the mouse away from it will no longer show that it's selected but it will keep it's text color.

Here is the full code:

Html: https://codetidy.com/8744/

CSS: https://codetidy.com/8745/

So that I can better explain my problem here is an example:

Loads the website
[image]

Hovers over the about tab to click it
[image]

Then after tab has been clicked mouse has moved away but the tab didn't stay red
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a more specific CSS selector to your custom CSS:

```
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

[Working example of your code (after adding the class above)](https://jsfiddle.net/jessejjohnson/y58t702c/)

Answer (score 0):

As what I can see on your html code, why do you have a onClick function for tabs. There is already a documentation for bootstrap tabs. You just need to clear up your css also to get the desired output. You can do something like this as css but it is much better if you put an id for you navbar.

default:

```
.nav > li { 
//enter code here  
}
```

hover:

```
.nav > li:hover { 
//enter code here  
}
```

selected:

```
.nav > li.active { 
//enter code here  
}
```